# Placing comma after words in IntelliJ IDEA(not by coding)

Tags: intellij-idea

My question is can you place a comma after every word?

Lets say I have got a lot of values, but those are only separated by a spaces or enters.
I want to place them in an array but don’t want to place a comma after every word one by one, so is there a key shortcut for this?

Example:
Mercury
Venus
Earth
Mars
Jupiter
Saturn
Uranus
Neptune

What I want to get:
Mercury,
Venus,
Earth,
Mars,
Jupiter,
Saturn,
Uranus,
Neptune

Comment: sure. have you checked the options that the String class provide?

Comment: Well, you have a `String[]`, the elements in it like, `Mercury` `Venus`, and what do you want? Another `String[]`, in which the elemnts are `Mercury,`...? Or you just need a `String` which contact all elements?

Comment: For example i have got a list in a notebook what i have to work with, I copy those values and paste them in the IDE, but those only separated by spaces or enters

Comment: I’m not sure what does the String class provide

Comment: @Sun it seems he has a String in the form of: "Mercury Venus Earth..." and wants "Mercury, Venus, Earth,..."

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with `java`. It's ide relevant. Please edit the question and tag it with your ide.

Comment: @DüsüngülüTibor You are using an IDE, which would no doubt offer an autocomplete functionality, there is the online documentation, what more do you need to try?

Comment: Yes, you are right stultuske

Comment: @Sun how on earth is this IDE relevant? if I understand his question correctly, a simple "replaceAll" would do the trick

Comment: I’m using intellij IDEA

Comment: @DüsüngülüTibor do you have a String like "Mercury Venus Earth.." in your code?

Comment: No, its not in the code, it is in a notepad and i have to work with those values

Comment: so .. this question is not even code/programming related?

Comment: In a way it is programming related question

Comment: how? are you reading this file into a piece of code and do you want to add the ,'s there?

Comment: Yes, i want to copy those values into my IDE from a notepad and in the notpad those values only separated by spaces or enters

Comment: @Stultuske He's searching for a shortcut to replace some words with others in IntelliJ IDE. And IntelliJ does have this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has this function

1. select the words `Mercury Venus Earth Mars Jupiter Saturn Uranus Neptune` in the editor
2. enter <kbd>ctrl + R</kbd>
3. click `regex`
4. search with `([a-z]+)`, replace with `$1,` which will append a comma after every words.
5. click replace all

For example,

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @DüsüngülüTibor No problem. Do you mind edit your question to clarify your attemp appropriatly? SInce some people are trying to help by coding.

Comment: Yes i hope (not by coding) is enough :D

Comment: And is there a way to do the same thing in NetBeans?

Comment: Sorry.. I'm not a NetBean user ..

Comment: Okay, no probs, thanks for your answer anyway it helps me a lot :d